# Get Distinct ID's in the last month grouped by date

Tags: sql, looker

I have a table with two columns EventDate and ClientID ( both are not unique)

| EventDate | ClientID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 | A101 |
| 2022-02-28 | A102 |
| 2022-02-28 | A101 |
| 2022-02-28 | A103 |
| 2022-02-27 | A101 |
| 2022-02-01 | A103 |

I am looking get an output showing the EventDate and Count Distinct ClientID in the last 30 days for each EventDate.

| EventDate | User_Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-28 | 3 |
| 2022-02-27 | 2 |
| 2022-02-01 | 1 |

I tried to do a self (left) join on the table, which works. But since the table is large (around 2Mn rows), the self join takes forever to complete.

```
    Select A.EventDate,
    Count (Distinct B.ClientID)
    from Table A
    left join Table B
    on B.EventDate between A.EventDate and DateAdd(DD, -30,A.EventDate)
    Group By A.EventDate
```

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Show what you've tried, sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added details, let me know if anything else

Comment: I don't think there's much else you can change and it probably comes down to indexing. You haven't tagged your RDBMS (is [meta-tag:Looker] relevant here?) Possibly a lateral join might be more performant if your RDBMS supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. You should not need to join back to the same table.

```
Select EventDate, Count (Distinct ClientID)
from Table
where EventDate >= DateAdd(DD, -30,GETDATE())
Group By EventDate
```